# Should the "too many pending edits" pop-up be reworded for accuracy (unless rejected edits have no effect on the number pending)?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, wording, error-message

As per this pop-up, I have maxed out on my pending edits:

> [image: too many pending edits pop-up]

For those who cannot read screen images, it says with my emboldenment:

> You have too many pending edits.  Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been **approved**.

Not all edits get approved, some get rejected, so I suggest that this should read **reviewed** or similar.

That is unless it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) with the intent that rejects do not reduce the pending queue, but this would end up with the (absurd) situation if all edit suggestions are rejected one would end up with an unreconcilable edit "ban" *ad infinitum* (or maybe until they earn sufficient reputation).

Comment: Nice catch! Yeah this is small change that does make sense, IMO. (And no, rejected edit is not pending anymore.)